# What does the error "Uncaught Exception: Uncaught RestRequestError - Unexpected error when communicating with server." mean?

Tags: ibm-cloud

I am using the Hybrid SDK with the Mobile Data service on Bluemix.I execute the `query.find()` method against one of my classess and get:

```
Uncaught Exception: Uncaught RestRequestError - Unexpected error when communicating with server
```

What is the cause of this error and how can I get my call to `query.find()` to complete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upon further testing I found that this ONLY occurs when I use the `query.find()` method against a class with many objects. I've tested 1k objects, 3k objects and 6k objects and I get the error each time.

When I tested with 500 objects I did not receive the error, so the problem seems to be related to the number of objects associated with the class I'm querying against.

A little further investigation revealed that for the classes with more objects the `query.find()` call was timing out.

I ended up implementing a call to `IBMBluemix.getConfig().setTimout()` into my code.  This increases the timeout value so that the `query.find()` call can complete. I had to experiment with values, mileage will vary.

Truth be told for some of my largest classes I'm looking at reducing the number of associated objects.